# Ansible playbooks

Tags: linux, ansible

I haven't used Ansible before, does anyone know how to write a simple playbook that uninstalls nano and installs vim on a Linux server? I would imagine you would need to include an option to configure which text editor preference you want after doing the above.

Cheers

**edit**

This is what I've got so far...

```
---
# Playbook to uninstall nano and install vim

  - hosts: all
    remote_user: luca
    sudo: yes

  tasks:
  - name: uninstall nano
    action: command: sudo apt-get purge nano

  - name: Install vim
    action: command: sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: Most Linux distributions include both nano and Vim. The two text editors have been living happily together for quite a long while so what problem exactly are you trying to fix?

Comment: @romainl it's just a task I've been set as part of a test for a job application, I'm kinda struggling to understand Ansible and how it would translate something like 'sudo apt-get purge nano' for example.

Comment: Besides that you are not using the `apt` module, as it is suggested in the answer below, in your example `tasks` indentation isn't correct. `tasks` should be indented the same as `hosts`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

tmp.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name: nano remove
     apt: name=nano state=absent
   - name: vim install
     apt: name=vim state=present
```

ansible-playbook tmp.yml

- http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks so much. I've been trying to write it but I have something completely different. See my edit in the original question ^

Comment: Would you mind explaining what's wrong with what I tried to do?

Comment: You don't use ansible apt or yum module, you can also do it with your method, using only command module but it's not correct method. Check ansible modules. nope.

Comment: As row, shell, command [modules](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_commands_modules.html) will do the trick for plain translation of bash scripts. They will rarely end up to be idempotent actions. They can not be run twice without producing errors.

The ansible way of doing this is to use the appropriate modules, in your case

 * [apt_key](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_key_module.html) : add the gpg key
 * [apt_repository](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_repository_module.html) : install the repository
 * [apt](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html) : install the package

Comment: I would add cache_valid_time=900000 and update_cache=true to the first apt module execution, as it will ensure you update apt cache the first time you run it.

Comment: you may want to also add `sudo: yes` on the line after `name: ...`, depending on whether you are running as root or normal user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on fedora/centos/rhel:

```
    ---    
    - hosts: all
      tasks:
       - name: nano remove
         yum: name=nano state=absent
       - name: vim install
         yum: name=vim state=latest
```

Refer to [doc of yum module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html) . Set proper args for "state": install (present or installed, latest), or remove (absent or removed) a package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove and install with command, you must write without 'action', like this:

```
tasks:
  - name: uninstall nano
    command: sudo apt-get purge nano

  - name: Install vim
    command: sudo apt-get install vim
```

But it is not recommended, it is better doing with 'absent'.
And I am not sure if can put sudo, so you can connect directly with your root user.

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  sudo: True
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally find it cleaner with a loop for the installs. For the uninstall just change the "state"

```
hosts: desktop-linux
tasks:
- name: Install Desktop packages
  apt: name={{item}} state=installed
  with_items:
    - meld
    - synergy
    - retext
    - pidgin
    - steam
    - ubuntu-restricted-extras
    - nautilus-admin
    - unity-tweak-tool
    - vlc
```